# processing zipped xml files in hadoop using mapreduce

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file structure like this.

a.zip contains a1.zip,a2.zip,a3.zip and then each of these zipped files have one xml file per zip.

I need to process these xml files. currently I am extracting zipped files from a.zip, storing them in hdfs and running a MR job to process a1.zip, a2.zip ..... using custom input format and record reader.

Can anyone help me with a better solution where I dont have to unzip a.zip and still process the files in parallel.

Comment: how about mentioning {codec} class for your input format class ..

{FileInputFormat.setInputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class)}

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a normal java pre-processor class which you can call from the main program. The steps would be:

1) pre-processor class would programmatically extracts the a.zip file into a temp location.

2) programmatically add the child zip classes to hdfs.

3) fire the XML processing in the way you are doing now.

4) if you wish, you can extend the pre-processor class to directly place XML, such that you could keep xml processing program simpler.

Let me know if something is not clear here.